# Transfer files using scp while connected to ngrok

Tags: 20.04, ssh, scp

I installed ngrok to connect via ssh to my work server from home or anywhere.

The ssh connection works perfectly and I have easy access to my files. The point is that I do not know how to copy them to the laptop from which I am connecting.

That is, I connect to the server using ssh from my laptop, using:

```
ssh myuser@999.tcp.ngrok.io -p 1234567
```

Now, how can I copy files or folders using scp from that server that has ngrok to my laptop? In aws is easy to do with a command like:

```
scp -i file.pem -r ubuntu@ec2-xx-xxx-xxx-xx.zone.compute.amazonaws.com:file_to_copy.txt
```

But how to do it while I am connected to ngrok?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using -P option for specifying the port. NOTE: it is capital P.

For example:

```
scp -P 1234567 myFile.extn myuser@999.tcp.ngrok.io:~/$HOME/.
```

Comment: Despite I already solved a few months ago, you answer is correct!